# Cannot determine embedded database driver class for database type NONE Exception with Spring and JavaFX

Tags: java, spring, maven, intellij-idea, javafx

I want to use Spring's auto-configuration feature to connect and create-drop a datasource.

I'm using JavaFX, Spring and Maven on IntelliJ. I first run 'mvn install' then run the jar file. However, I'm getting the following error even though I believe I have followed the right steps:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceProperties$DataSourceBeanCreationException: Cannot determine embedded database driver class for database type NONE. If you want an embedded database please put a supported one on the classpath. If you have database settings to be loaded from a particular profile you may need to active it (no profiles are currently active).
at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceProperties.determineDriverClassName(DataSourceProperties.java:246)
at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceProperties.initializeDataSourceBuilder(DataSourceProperties.java:183)
at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceConfiguration.createDataSource(DataSourceConfiguration.java:42)
at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceConfiguration$Tomcat.dataSource(DataSourceConfiguration.java:56)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:162)
... 47 more
```

I have defined my datasource properties in my application.properties file under src/main/resources:

```
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/project_name?autoReconnect=true&useSSL=false
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=password

spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop
spring.jpa.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.globally_quoted_identifiers=true
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
```

My build details and dependencies in my pom.xml:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.7.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.7.RELEASE</version>
</parent>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.7.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.7.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>6.0.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.12.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>3.5.6-Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
        <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
        <version>2.9.9</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.12</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
        <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
        <version>23.1-jre</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

My Main class that starts the program is:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@ComponentScan
public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        Parent root = SpringFXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/welcome.fxml"), ResourceBundle.getBundle("language", new Locale("en")));
        stage.setTitle("Softserver");
        stage.setScene(new Scene(root));
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

My custom SpringFXMLLoader class:

```
public class SpringFXMLLoader {

    private static final ApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext("package_name");

    public static <T> T load(URL url, ResourceBundle languageProperties) {
        try {
            FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(url, languageProperties);
            loader.setControllerFactory(context::getBean);
            return loader.load();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
}
```

What else am I missing here? Any help would greatly be appreciated!

Comment: Can you verify that your `application.properties` file is present in the jar file (and is in the root of the classpath)?

Comment: Thanks for helping! When I run `mvn install` it creates a target folder that contains the jar file, however I'm not sure how to see the src code of the jar file. I can see my `application.properties` under target/classes.

Comment: Just do `jar tf TheFile.jar` from the command line. If it's deployed to `target/classes` it is likely present in the jar.

Comment: It's present in the jar file under BOOT-INF\classes.